# Jquery Custom event triggers

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

I am having some trouble understanding custom event triggers. I have some code to trigger a custom event on ALL elements (as per the docs)

```
$.event.trigger('modal:close',[$d]);
```

`$d` is a jquery object

if I bind on to document like so:

```
$(document).on('modal:close',function(event,element) {
    console.log('Triggered');
});
```

Then my handler is called logging "Triggered" to the console. However if I bind it to a specific element like so:

```
$("#foo").on('modal:close',function(event,element) {
    console.log('Triggered');
});
```

Then the trigger is never caught and nothing is logged.

Am I missing something from the docs in that $.event.trigger('foo') doesn't call said event on ALL elements that could be listening or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to raise the event on both elements in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ogmo5dL5/. Can you provide more information about your code.

Comment: He tries to trigger it with $.event.trigger('modal:close',[$d]); which only triggers to document.

Comment: Your code is different to mine. Here is my version updated on your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ogmo5dL5/1/

Comment: It appears that the documentation is wrong and triggering on all elements is not available in modern jQuery's. At this point I ave implemented a publish / subscribe pattern and will make do with that until I can find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the documentation is wrong and triggering on all elements is not available in modern jQuery's. At this point I ave implemented a publish / subscribe pattern and will make do with that until I can find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$d.trigger('modal:close');
```